# Change shortcuts in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 Bit)

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit, would like to change some of my shortcuts, especially the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> combination (to switch applications). However it simply doesn't work: All changes under "Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts" have no effect. I also installed the dconf Editor, but it isn't working either. Has anybody an idea what I could do?

(The reason why I want to change shortcuts is, that I'm playing an old video-game via wine, where one can't change the keybindings. <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd> have to be used a lot in that game, and because I'm playing in fullscreen-mode, this will totally break my session: The computer leaves fullscreen mode and opens up the desktop, and it's impossible to return to the game; I have to kill wine and start it again.)

Comment: maybe you already tried, but what is the (terminal) output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications`?

Comment: It's '@as []' (because I have - without any effect - disabled the command under "Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts" and with the dconf Editor.)